# Is there a way to get synchronous terminal input in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stdin

I have looked at similar questions on SO and I have an ongoing question about if it is possible to get synchronous input from the command line.

I know about `readline` and `process.stdin.on('readable', ...)` but both of those seem to be asynchronous.

I am looking to for a way to prompt the user for input where code later on in my script does not run before there is user input.

Comment: Why don't you make the code execute only after the data is read?

Comment: This module seems to do what you want: https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync

Comment: @thefourtheye the input was supposed to be during a recursive function where each file in a directory is added.  I think this would make it much harder.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this in case if you know fix number of inputs you want in sync manner.

```
    const readline = require('readline');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });
    let i = 0;
    rl.question('Number of inputs : ', (answer1) => {
      rl.on('line', (answer2) => {
        console.log(`input: ${answer2}`);
        i++;
        if (i >= answer1) {
          rl.close();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: This is not synchronous at all. It's based on callbacks.